# Docker & PostgreSQL- modified PostgreSQL image doesn't start with Docker run command

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to to build a PostgreSQL image that only contains some extra .sql files to be executed at starting time

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11.9-alpine
USER postgres
WORKDIR /
COPY ddl/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Then I build the image:

```
docker build -t my-postgres:1.0.0 -f Dockerfile .
```

And run the container

```
docker run -d --name my-database \
           -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abc123 \
           -p 5432:5432 \
           my-postgres:1.0.0
```

The output of it is the container id

```
33ed596792a80fc08f37c7c0ab16f8827191726b8e07d68ce03b2b5736a6fa4e
```

Checking the running containers returns nothing:

```
Docker container ls
```

But if I explicitly start it, it works

```
docker start my-postgres
```

In the original PostgreSQL image the Docker run command already starts the database. Why after building my own image it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that one of the copied *.sql* files was failing to execute and, based on this [documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#initialization-scripts), it makes the entrypoint script to exit. Fixing the SQL solved the issue and the container started normally with *Docker run*